# Can you have hyperlinks to locations in different PDFs?

Tags: pdf, links, html, pdftricks

It's possible to [hyperlink to another PDF](http://yihui.name/en/2008/10/how-to-open-a-file-from-a-hyperlink/) file using Adobe Acrobat using the following LaTeX code:

```
\href{run:target.pdf}{Click me!}
```

If this is placed in `source.pdf`, then you can click on the hyperlink to open up `target.pdf` on the front page.

Is there any chance of hyperlinking to a *different* section in another PDF, similar to `second.html#target` in HTML?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

(for reference the [Adobe Knowledge base entry about pdf from html linking](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/317/317300.html))

Checkout section 4.1 in [Hypertext capabilities with pdfLaTeX (F. Garcia, TUGBoat, Vol. 28, No. 1, 2007)](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb28-1/tb88garcia.pdf), which describes the `hyperdef` and `hyperref` commands.

Just a small example:

src.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{Source a}
\hyperdef{cat1}{link1}
Foo bar
\hyperref{dest.pdf}{cat1}{link1}{Link 1}

\section{Source b}
\hyperdef{cat2}{link2}
Fu baz
\hyperref{dest.pdf}{cat2}{link2}{Link 2}
\end{document}
```

dest.tex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\section{One}
\lipsum

\section{Two}
\hyperdef{cat1}{link1}
Fill paragraph.
\hyperref{src.pdf}{cat1}{link1}{Back 1}
\lipsum

\section{Three}
\hyperdef{cat2}{link2}
Fill paragraph.
\hyperref{src.pdf}{cat2}{link2}{Back 2}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Create the PDFs via:

```
$ pdflatex src
$ pdflatex dest
```

Now you can try to jump back and forth between the both documents in your favorite PDF Viewer.

(Tested it with [Okular](http://okular.kde.org/) under Ubuntu 10.04)

Comment: Note if you use `gs` to "compress" the PDF the links can be gone. One can easily use `extractpdfmark` to workaround the issue. See https://bugs.ghostscript.com/show_bug.cgi?id=695760