# Changing the paper size of a document without changing anything else

Tags: conversion, paper-size

I found a nice piece of software (pdf2swf) that converts pdf files to browse-able flash files, but prevents them from being downloaded.

I have a "book" document that I wrote in LaTeX and I want to host it on a website as an swf file (so that it can be read but not downloaded).

The problem I'm having is that the 8.5in x 11in paper size scales very narrow to fit on the screen; I tried manipulating the paper size, but it smashed my text around and some of the text disappeared.

Is there a simple way to compile a LaTeX book document so that it will change the paper size but nothing else?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) If my answer isn't at all what you're looking for, you could perhaps specify what you mean with "the 8.5x11 paper size scales very narrow to fit on the screen" and "change the aspect ratio".

Comment: Oh and it'd be good if we could find a more accurate title. You're working on a problem on the way to _Flash pdf with LaTeX_, but this is not the problem itself. If my guess was correct, the title could be something like _Converting letter paper to A4 paper without changing anything else_.

Comment: @doncherry I think you're right; I was just holding out hope that someone would say "Oh, if you want to stream a pdf without it being downloadable, there is this piece of software / html one-liner / etc. ..."

Comment: pdf2swf definitely sounds like a neat tool, but one question should be on one topic. We can provide links to related questions in comments and the questions themselves. If you wanna share pdf2swf expressedly with the tex.sx community, you could check if there's any question asking for non-downloadable online solutions; if there is one, post it as an answer, if not, ask a question and answer it yourself after a day or two. I did the same thing with http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25919/. You might want to check out http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4/ first.

Comment: Are you doing this to prevent people from copying your text?

Comment: Exactly-- any ideas? I looked into some of the flash options, but it's a bit tricky to embed if the pdf is 8.5x11.

Comment: @Oliver No, it's just that I wonder what reason you have for wanting to prevent people from copying your text? If it's really a meaningful thing to do. The ability to copy text makes it easier for people to cite you and your text might get more readers if it's easy to access.

Comment: You can't prevent people from copying your text: all they need is a thing called a secretary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but with the following you can convert a document on letter paper (8.5in x 11in) to A4 paper (210mm x 297mm) and it looks like nothing else changes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,noautoscale]{myfabulousbookinletterformat.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Because `8.5in − 210mm = 6mm`, there's a little bit chopped off at the sides; and because `11in − 297mm = −17.6mm`, there's additional space at the bottom and the top, but you can't get around this if you don't want to change anything else. (I'm assuming you don't want to "stretch-to-fit" your document, that would just look terrible.) So if you have elements really close to the edge of the paper, they'll get cut off.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if I can do this with {book} instead of article? I use \part{...} in my document.

Comment: @Oliver: You could certainly just try it. It's not necessary though. Finish your document (with the `book` documentclass) all the way and compile it by itself, in letter format. Then compile the document I posted with the name of your book file instead of `myfabulousbookinletterformat.pdf`. This document only changes the page format, so the relatively simple `article` class suffices, `book` is unnecessarily complex and might or might not trigger problems. All of your `\part{...}`s stay in your `myfabulousbookinletterformat.tex`.

Comment: +1 Great, thanks! I don't know why I thought \part wouldn't work for article.