# link to a specific worksheet in an excel file

Tags: links

Can a link as in `\href{run:./400.xls} {\textcolor{blue}{400}}` be specific to a certain worksheet in an excel file, or to even a certain cell.

Comment: Does Excel support this? If so, then... sure. If not, then, well, no. This might be border-line off-topic, as it doesn't really depend on (La)TeX, I think.

Comment: if Excel can support this, what is the code I can use to try it.

Comment: If you have a document with such a working link, copy the link (in Firefox is right-click, "copy link location") and then paste it in a text file --- now you can put it into a `\href` or `\url` command. If you have problems, copy the link here and someone will help. This is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25919/external-html-link-to-a-specific-page-of-a-pdf-file?rq=1

Comment: I tried both \href{run:./xx.xls#page=AllRooms} , and \href{run:./xx.xls#worksheet=AllRooms} where AllRooms is the name of the worksheet inside xx.xls file. Neither is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question in
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854263/what-the-win-cmd-to-open-a-particular-spreadsheet-in-excel

I am trying to get more specific answer in 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34460028/editing-vbs-to-accept-a-parameter