# xr and hyperref to link between two PDF documents

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, pdf, xr

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does hyperref work between two files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41539/does-hyperref-work-between-two-files)

I am using the `xr` package to write a PDF document that contains references to another PDF document, like "in section bla of the other document...".  For example, in the referred document there is this code:

```
\section{Bla}
\label{sec:bla}
```

and in the referring document there is this code:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xr}
...
in Section~\ref{sec:bla} in the other document...
```

The cross-referencing works - the ref appears with the correct section number.

Can I use `hyperref` together with `xr` to make the link actually point to a page in the other document, so when it is clicked, the right place in the other document will pop up?  It is OK to assume that both file are in the same dir.

Comment: I saw that this can be done explicitly using `\hyperdef` and `\hyperref` [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6210/can-you-have-hyperlinks-to-locations-in-different-pdfs).  Can it be done automatically just using `xr` and cross-references?

Answer (score 4):

`hyperref` comes with a modified version of `xr`, `xr-hyper` with the same user interface but matching hyperref internals.