# hyperref: can I control how to display the PDF?

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, pdf

I use the method described in this link for getting hyperlinks from different PDF files:

[Can you have hyperlinks to locations in different PDFs?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6210/can-you-have-hyperlinks-to-locations-in-different-pdfs/6220#6220)

I would like to remain with two open PDF files, source and destination. When I use the described method, the source PDF is replaced by the target PDF.

Can I control how to display the PDF files?

Answer (score 7):

Option `pdfnewwindow` controls this behaviour, e.g.:

```
\usepackage[pdfnewwindow]{hyperref}
```

or

```
\hypersetup{pdfnewwindow}
```

The latter can also be used in a local group. The setting is disabled by setting to `false`:

```
\hypersetup{pdfnewwindow=false}
```

Comment: \documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[pdfnewwindow]{hyperref}
\begin{document}  And I have result: Option clash for package hyperref.

Comment: @Jana You cannot load a LaTeX package with new options after it is loaded (the exception is package `fontenc`). Use the options in the first call of `\usepackage` or use `\hypersetup` for this option.

Comment: Heiko, and how I can control position and size of new oppened PDFs window?

Comment: @Jana You cannot. It is a matter of the PDF viewer, window manager, ...; but it is *not* a property that can be set in the PDF file.